# How Iterate in a folder on s3 by using boto3?

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, boto3

In my instance in the s3 I have a folder with N files, I need to iterate in this using this script bellow, I need to get all files and convert it, this script is hosted on a ec2 instance working with django.

I tryed a lot, by using the boto3 function get_object but all I get is nothing.

Can someone tell please how can I do something like that?, I'll need to download this files before convert or can I do it directly?

```
 def upload_folder_to_s3(local_folder, destination_folder, s3_bucket):
    '''
    Function to upload a specific local folder to S3 bucket.

    Parameters:
    local_folder (str): Path to local folder.
    destination_folder (str): Path to destination folder on S3.
    s3_bucket (str): Bucket name on S3.

    Return:
    '''
    # Global variables
    global client

    # Iterate over files on folder
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(local_folder):
        for filename in files:
            print(filename)
            # construct the full local path
            local_path = os.path.join(root, filename)

            # construct the full Dropbox path
            relative_path = os.path.relpath(local_path, local_folder)
            s3_path = os.path.join(destination_folder, relative_path)

            # relative_path = os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root, filename))

            print('Searching "%s" in "%s"' % (s3_path, s3_bucket))
            try:
                client.get_object(Bucket=s3_bucket, Key=s3_path)
                print("Path found on S3! Skipping %s..." % s3_path)

                # try:
                    # client.delete_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=s3_path)
                # except:
                    # print "Unable to delete %s..." % s3_path
            except:
                print("Uploading %s..." % s3_path)
                client.upload_file(local_path, s3_bucket, s3_path)
    return local_folder
```

Comment: So, you are saying that the problem is with `upload_file()`? You should confirm each of the 3 parameters to make sure they are valid. Try hard-coding the values to verify that it works, then put back the variables and figure out which ones were wrong. It could be that your `root` contains a device identifier or a leading slash, which are not valid for S3.